if value of a hash map is also a hash container, e.g., unordered_map<int, unordered_set<...>>, how to specify customized hash & equal for the value?
Say now I have hash and equal functions ready for an unordered_set
auto equalFunc = [](...){...};
auto hashFunc  = [](...){...};

If the unordered_set is used solely, I know I can do the following to specify my DIY hash and equal:
std::unordered_set<std::pair<int,int>, decltype( hashFunc ), decltype( equalFunc )> mySet( 0, hashFunc, equalFunc );

However, now suppose the unordered_set is to be used as value of std::unordered_map, how can I specify the hash and equal?
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<std::pair<int,int>, decltype( hashFunc ), decltype( equalFunc )>> myMap( ...how? );


As haser/comparer are stateless and default constructible, you might simply omit them in constructor...

@Jarod42 Lambdas cannot be constructed from type: https://godbolt.org/z/WMhKP9Eor. It may work the other way round (omit template types), not sure how the deduction guides are defined for std::unordered_set.

@Yksisarvinen: Since C++20, non-capture lambdas are default-constructible, and then it works Demo.

For previous version (and even for recent version :-) ), I suggest to use the "old" way using a classical Functor instead of lambda (see MarekR's answer).

@Jarod42 Good to know, thanks!

You need to do the std::unordered_set construction, with the functions, when you insert an element into the map:
myMap[some_key] = std::unordered_set<std::pair<int,int>, decltype( hashFunc ), decltype( equalFunc )>( 0, hashFunc, equalFunc );

It would of course be simpler if you used an alias for the type:
using mySetType = std::unordered_set<std::pair<int,int>, decltype( hashFunc ), decltype( equalFunc )>;

// ...

myMap[some_key] = mySetType( 0, hashFunc, equalFunc );


Many thanks for you answer mate. I assume the decltype( hashFunc ), decltype( equalFunc ) thing is still necessary right?

@PkDrew Yes it's still needed, but with an alias for the set type you should not have to write it as much. :-)

True, crystal clear now, cheers :)

Lambdas are cool, but not in this context. I would define a class for hash and equal functions.
Using couple type aliases makes this much more handy.
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

using Value = std::pair<int, int>;

struct EqualValue {
    bool operator()(const Value& a, const Value& b) const noexcept;
};

struct HashValue {
    size_t operator()(const Value& a) const noexcept;
};

using ValueSet = std::unordered_set<Value, HashValue, EqualValue>;

using Foo = std::unordered_map<int, ValueSet>;

https://godbolt.org/z/zxqsb3s4b
